# pivot longer in R for multiple variables with the different suffix

Tags: pivot, multiple-columns

I want to transfer my data from wide to long format. My data looks like this:

```
  province_code        SA_X1        SB_X1        SC_X1
1            01 2.196310e-03 3.203745e-03 2.232292e-03
2            02 5.498124e-06 3.657642e-07 5.684323e-07
         SD_X1        SE_X1        SF_X1        SG_X1
1 8.557088e-03 7.031706e-03 3.628405e-04 3.453302e-03
2 1.422532e-05 6.640942e-06 5.869621e-08 6.613530e-07
         SH_X1        SK_X1        SL_X1        SM_X1
1 3.925176e-03 3.817800e-03 4.684686e-03 3.694667e-03
2 4.211355e-07 5.553989e-06 3.554995e-06 1.090183e-06
         SN_X1        SO_X1        SP_X1        SA_X2       SB_X2
1 5.726985e-03 6.887345e-03 6.544230e-03 0.0023154926 0.003527706
2 2.786146e-06 5.660139e-06 8.634686e-06 0.0009851886 0.001334634
        SC_X2       SD_X2       SE_X2        SF_X2       SG_X2
1 0.002665430 0.002749958 0.003663561 0.0018152021 0.002858403
2 0.001087497 0.001619690 0.001553579 0.0009370408 0.001253056
        SH_X2       SK_X2       SL_X2       SM_X2       SN_X2
1 0.003278626 0.003967366 0.004326396 0.012286509 0.006032205
2 0.001318002 0.001514260 0.001510185 0.002547837 0.001812679
        SO_X2       SP_X2        SA_X3        SB_X3        SC_X3
1 0.007137097 0.003152035 3.109918e-03 3.361255e-03 1.117508e-03
2 0.002131557 0.001502918 3.481705e-05 8.929936e-06 7.848717e-06
         SD_X3        SE_X3        SF_X3        SG_X3
1 6.241172e-03 5.696914e-03 0.0023752320 4.603526e-03
2 1.105289e-05 1.027453e-05 0.0000138821 1.262974e-05
         SH_X3        SK_X3        SL_X3        SM_X3
1 4.860335e-03 5.427030e-03 5.149588e-03 4.399737e-03
2 5.510878e-06 1.371773e-05 5.029771e-06 1.226403e-05
         SN_X3        SO_X3        SP_X3       SA_X4       SB_X4
1 8.951200e-03 1.149814e-02 5.226682e-03 0.003136327 0.003774786
2 3.284164e-05 3.420453e-05 3.590607e-05 0.001361359 0.001436113
         SC_X4       SD_X4       SE_X4       SF_X4       SG_X4
1 0.0020608482 0.002234351 0.004414011 0.003012488 0.004358894
2 0.0009567918 0.001326035 0.001584367 0.001324841 0.001591633
        SH_X4       SK_X4       SL_X4      SM_X4       SN_X4
1 0.005718995 0.006474799 0.006734541 0.01555500 0.005748706
2 0.001727003 0.002066540 0.001895804 0.00314947 0.002221513
        SO_X4       SP_X4
1 0.009248575 0.006660019
2 0.003034850 0.002098157type here
```

I want to transfer my data to long format. The desired outcome is:

```
province_code   newsector   X1  X2  X3  X4
01  SA  .0021963    .0023155    .0031097    .0031363
01  SB  .0032037    .0035277    .003361     .0037748
01  SC  .0022323    .0026654    .0011174    .0020608
01  SD  .0085571    .00275      .0062407    .0022344
01  SE  .0070317    .0036636    .0056965    .004414
01  SF  .0003628    .0018152    .0023751    .0030125
01  SG  .0034533    .0028584    .0046032    .0043589
01  SH  .0039252    .0032786    .00486      .005719
01  SK  .0038178    .0039674    .0054266    .0064748
01  SL  .0046847    .0043264    .0051492    .0067345
01  SM  .0036947    .0122865    .0043994    .015555
01  SN  .005727     .0060322    .0089505    .0057487
01  SO  .0068873    .0071371    .0114973    .0092486
01  SP  .0065442    .003152     .0052263    .00666
type here
```

I read different posts about pivot longer and I think we need to apply "name pattern" or " ends_with" in pivot longer to break down the values names in the initial data set to set up the long format. I am new to R and really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!